# Run a loop while waiting for input

Tags: python

Example

```
x = 0    
while True:
    x += 1
    input = input("whats the day like")
```

I want it so x will continue going up while waiting for the input

Comment: Incidentally, doing `input=input(...)` will shadow the function and will produce an error next time you call it. You should use an other variable name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a counter look at time module and calculate time before and after the user input and take the difference to get the time taken for user input.

use `time.time()` to capture the time at particular instance.

Comment: so are you saying I would calculate how long its been since user input and once they put a input i add the amount of time onto the variable? or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It's great to see a new user on StackOverflow.

I was able to find a solution using the threading module in Python. One way to think about threading in Python is by imagining two Python scripts running simultaneously, but this is not an entirely thorough explanation. To learn more, I would suggest referring to one of the pages below.

Links:

https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#what-is-a-thread
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Example:

```
import threading

def thread_function(args):
    for x in range(args):
        print(x)

x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(5,))
x.start()

input = input("whats the day like")
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
whats the day like4
```

Where it waits for user input at the end.

Comment: so if i wear to use this would it allow x to go up even when waiting for input only go up a certian amount of times then ask for input? also thanks I hope to be using overflow alot since im just starting out in python

Comment: If you declare the variable x outside of the threading function then you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this just for timing:

```py
from time import perf_counter

start = perf_counter()
inp = input()
print(inp)
print(f"You inserted input in : {perf_counter() - start}")
```

If by any reason you want to increment `x`, do the increment part in a separate thread:

```py
from time import sleep
import threading

x = 0
def increment():
    global x
    while True:
        x += 1
        print(f"X is now: {x}")
        sleep(1)

threading.Thread(target=increment, daemon=True).start()

inp = input()
print(f"input is: {inp}")
```

output:

```
X is now: 1
X is now: 2
X is now: 3
hi
input is: hi
```

By specifying `daemon=True`, the `increment` thread doesn't prevent interpreter from terminating.

If you want to stop the thread whenever you receive input, use [event object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects):

```py
from time import sleep
import threading

event = threading.Event()

x = 0
def increment():
    global x
    while not event.is_set():
        x += 1
        print(f"X is now: {x}")
        sleep(1)

threading.Thread(target=increment).start()

inp = input()
event.set()
print(f"input is: {inp}")
```